# I need to understand J query and its nested functionality> how can i nest one function into another function using same target?

Tags: html, jquery

**````
I am a beginner and I got this sample code from w3schools.
I would like to modify this code in suchaway that it should stop after the animation expands. Once when click the button again, it has to contract. Is it possible? how am I supposed to nest that function inside another function to the same command button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var div = $("div");
    div.animate({height: '300px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
    div.animate({width: '300px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
    div.animate({height: '100px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
    div.animate({width: '100px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's one of way doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/jgbwvd57/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var div = $("div");
    if (div.is(':animated')) {
      div.finish();
    } else {
      div.animate({ height: "300px", opacity: "0.4" }, "slow");
      div.animate({ width: "300px", opacity: "0.8" }, "slow");
      div.animate({ height: "100px", opacity: "0.4" }, "slow");
      div.animate({ width: "100px", opacity: "0.8" }, "slow");
    }
  });
});
```

You can use the object of `.finish`. When `.finish()` is called on an element, the currently-running animation and all queued animations (if any) immediately stop and their CSS properties set to their target values. All queued animations are removed.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/finish/

If you want to stop the code during animation, you should check it and use `if` and `else` conditions when animation is going on.

The code is detect the animation in JQuery

```
if (element.is(':animated')) {
  // Do something
  // Element has animate
} else {
  // Do something
  // Element not has animate
}
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: Thanks for the code. What i am looking was that when I click the button, it should expand the pixels. I then have to press the same button to contract the same. Can we do that ?